# ODBC connection to oracle time-out

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc, tnsnames

I'm new here so I introduce myself, my name is Ettore Giallaurito and my job is in the IT services in Italy.

My question:

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB instance through an odbc (System DNS) connections under XP but I get an error ORA1254 TNS:could not resolvethe connect identifier specified.

I'm using oracle instant client 11.2 and I've my tnsnames properly configured, since I can get connected with DBVisualizer using the TNS method. 
To be honest I do get connected in this case, but I need to insert the full connect string:

```
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = repsit01.sit.sor)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = REPSIT01))
  )
```

since it doesn't get me in if I use just the SID, in my case REPSIT01 as showed below.

My tns entry is as follow:

```
REPSIT01 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = REPSIT01))
  )
```

Any help would be much apprecciated.

Thanks in advance Ettore.

Comment: you may have multiple clients, just a guess.  check your ORACLE_HOME location, and try tnsping

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to the directory where your tnsnames.ora file resides.

Comment: My similar problem ended up being a typeo in my TNS_ADMIN variable.  With a bad TNS_ADMIN, you get an empty  list of TNS names in the System ODBC Driver config dialog.